# whenever i am trying to build my react project with vite, in the browser it is showing me some icons

Tags: reactjs, output, vite, symbols, execute

[my react output in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvsr3.png)

can anyone please help me out!!!

I tried to see my browser setting, if it is happening for Language preference, but seems like my browser setting is ok. I am still facing this issue. But whenever i copy those symbol and paste it to another terminal(of browser) those symbols paste as a letter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.